# How to have a proposition of comparing two 'int' types in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq, compcert

I have the following Definition in my spec file in Coq. I need to have a proposition comparing two "int" type values. These two are 't' and 'Int.repr (i.(period1))'.(i.period1) and (i.period2) have type 'Z'.

This is my code snippet:

```
Definition trans_uni_r_reject (i: invariant) (om os: block) (rid roff rval t: int) (m: mem) :=
  ( t > (Int.repr (i.(period1)))        
 /\ t < (Int.repr (i.(period2)))
 /\  master_eval_reject i om os rid roff rval m).
```

This gives me the error below:

***The term "t" has type "int" while it is expected to have type "Z"*.**

---

I also tried:

```
   (Int.cmpu Cgt t (Int.repr (i.(period1))))
/\ (Int.cmpu Clt t (Int.repr (i.(period2))))
/\ (master_eval_reject i om os rid roff rval m).
```

but it gives me this error:

***The term "Int.cmpu Cgt t (Int.repr (period1 i))" has type "bool" while it is expected to have type "Prop".***

Is there any way I can compare these two 'int' types or convert them to something else and return 'prop' type?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `bool` can be converted to a `Prop` by equating it to `true`. In your example, this would lead to:

```
   Int.cmpu Cgt t (Int.repr (i.(period1))) = true
/\ Int.cmpu Clt t (Int.repr (i.(period2))) = true
/\ master_eval_reject i om os rid roff rval m.
```

If you search results on the `Int.cmpu` operator, you'll probably find many lemmas in the `Int` module that are stated in terms of `Int.cmpu Cgt x y = true`. For this, you can use the `SearchAbout` command:

```
SearchAbout Int.cmpu. (* Looks for all results on Int.cmpu *)
SearchAbout Int.cmpu Cgt (* Looks for all results that mention
                            Int.cmpu and Cgt *)
```

## Coercions

Equating booleans to `true` is so common that people often declare a *coercion* to use booleans as if they were propositions:

```
Definition is_true (b : bool) : Prop := b = true.
Coercion is_true : bool >-> Sortclass.
```

Now, you can use any boolean in a context where a proposition is expected:

```
   Int.cmpu Cgt t (Int.repr (i.(period1)))
/\ Int.cmpu Clt t (Int.repr (i.(period2)))
/\ master_eval_reject i om os rid roff rval m.
```

Behind the scenes, Coq inserts invisible calls to `is_true` around those occurrences. You should be aware, though, that the coercions still appear in your terms. You can see this by issuing a special command,

```
Set Printing Coercions.
```

which would show you the above snippet as Coq sees it:

```
   is_true (Int.cmpu Cgt t (Int.repr (i.(period1))))
/\ is_true (Int.cmpu Clt t (Int.repr (i.(period2))))
/\ master_eval_reject i om os rid roff rval m.
```

(To undo the previous step, just run `Unset Printing Coercions`.)

Because coercions are not printed by default, it can take you some time to use them effectively. The [Ssreflect and MathComp](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/) Coq libraries make heavy use of `is_true` as a coercion, and have special support for making it simpler to use. If you're interested, I suggest you have a look at them!

Comment: Thanks Arthur! As you suggested, I declared a coercion and it solved my problem. :)

Comment: In addition to Arthur's excellent answer, I'd like to point out that proving with `is_true` leads a style of proving with rewrite, as indeed you may rewrite `A = true` to `true = true`.